# How can I find lost document created using Lubuntu guest account?

Tags: lubuntu, search, users

A friend used my old laptop to write an .rtf document.  Lacking the administrator password, he used a guest account.  Now I'm trying to get the document for him.

It seems that using a guest account requires a password I don't know.  Searching the hd while logged in to my account is turning anything up.  Perhaps docs created from another account are hidden from me, or perhaps I'm not searching right (using catfish because I am a novice user)?

Comment: i think your out of luck, AS FAR AS I KNOW guest account erases everything each time you logout, someone else might confirm this?

Comment: try looking in the tmp folder?

Comment: @Magpie, good idea, unfortunately I'm seeing an "access denied" message when I try to get into a sub-folder that looks promising.  Sam, wow that's brutal... is there a warning I missed somewhere?

Comment: Did you try using sudo when you went in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guest accounts store their home directory in /tmp.

So if you rebooted, the document is absolutely gone since tmp is not stored to disk.

If you didn't reboot, the home directory for the guest is in /tmp, it will be /tmp/guest-XXXXX, where XXXXX is a random string of characters. You can use sudo to look in that directory.

EDIT: Here's a simple way to take ownership of the guest directory so you can poke around in it, substituting the real directory name for XXXXX

```
 sudo chown -R `whoami`:`whoami` /tmp/guest-XXXXX
```

Once you do that just cd into that directory and poke around, or you can use Nautilus to look at files.